# Google App Engine Security Scanner gone crazy

Tags: google-app-engine

A couple of times I've noticed strange activity with our GAE demo app.  I'm seeing lots of activity in the developer console and also lots of hits on the signin page with Google Analytics.

The demo app shouldn't experience much activity.  We also have a test app and production app and they don't exhibit the activity.  We haven't turned on the Security Scanner for those sites.

[image]

At first I was suspicious, thinking that someone was trying to hack into the demo site. After investigating it seemed that the Security Scanner may be the culprit. The first time I stopped the scan, the activity stopped. But a couple of days ago some strange activity occurred again.  It looked like a security scan had been running for days.  So, I killed it and also deleted the Security scan.  However, the activity persists.

According to Google Analytics hits seem to come from specific geographical regions.

Any ideas as to how to really kill the Security Scanner?  Or is this activity something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: One other thing to consider is that we added support for the Google Measurement Protocol to the demo app.  Haven't released this to test or production apps.  Could this activity be related to that?

Comment: Anyone at google care to comment?  How can we stop the darn security scanner?